# $('input').each(function() { }); is not getting all the input boxes in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have document with many div and input boxes in it.

A few input boxes are inside a `div` of `.form-group` class. I used below script to alert out the the ids of all inputs. But it is not detecting some of the inputs.

```
$('input').each(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Do all the `input`s have `id`s?

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/  to create a repro of the issue. Otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?  This code alone isn't enough.

Comment: Are you working with dynamic added content? If thats the case you need to run your code after the content is added.

Comment: Another thing could be that you are calling your code snippet before the whole DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The selector `input` would only match `<input>` elements. It would not for example match `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements.

If you want to match all input elements, you can use the `:input` selector. Alternatively, you  can also specify the additional types in your selector.

For example:

```
$(':input')

// OR //

$('input, select, textarea')
```

Comment: I m trying to alert out only <input> element id's

Comment: @user3460350 In that case `$('input')` should have been sufficient. You should include your HTML. Also, consider Null's comment and answer above.

Answer (score 2):

When are your snippet called?

For instance....

```
<input id="id1">
<script>
    alert( $('input').length ) // will result in 1
</script>
<input id="id2">
```

Consider moving your snippet to the bottom of the body tag:

```
<input id="id1">
<input id="id2">
<script>
    alert( $('input').length ) // will result in 2
</script>
```

or wrap it as a `jQuery.ready` callback:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) { // called after the DOM is loaded.
        alert( $('input').length ) // will result in 2
    });
</script>
<input id="id1">
<input id="id2">
```

---

Note that a making a new jQuery instance (`jQuery(...)`) will take a "snapshot" of the current DOM structure and if something is added later it will not get updated:

```
<input>
<script> var $inputs = $('input'); </script>
<input>
<script> alert($inputs.length); // Still 1 because we took a "snapshot" when there was only 1 input element in the DOM </script>
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Boaz it was a comment but I wanted to add more examples than a comment can!